# user control Button click event called again when page is refreshed using F5

Tags: c#, vb.net

I found that if you press F5 or refress from browser window, the last event fires again
example, I have clicked on a button, the button event is carried out normally, but if I refresh the page by pressing F5 key the same event is fired again.

anyone have any Idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens there is that the refresh triggers the post back not just the page load -- so the event is triggered. A simple solution would be to redirect the user to a fresh new page after handling the event.

This way if the page is reloaded it's a new page, not the post back.